# Bootstrap Grid Layout without margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid

Okay, so I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659471/nested-rows-with-bootstrap-grid-system) but I couldn't get rid of  the margins, so If anyone has the solution for this. 
I would like to make this grid layout with no margins between each box.

[Grid Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux1YE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user .row to remove the margins

```css
.box {
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

#box-1 {
  background: #c39a6f;
}

#box-2 {
  background: #bcbec0;
}

#box-3 {
  background: #9a857a;
}

#box-4 {
  background: #3b2416;
}

#box-5 {
  background: #726659;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 box" id="box-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box" id="box-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box" id="box-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 box" id="box-4"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 box" id="box-5">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/3ejptrfp/1/)

For that purpose, you have to clear some `paddings` and try to use `flexbox` so that `box-5` will take a height of all left boxes. So that, even if height of left boxes increases, height of `box-5` will increase relatively.

**Your sample HTML**

```
<div class="main-wrapper"> 
    <div class="col-sm-8 left-wrapper">
        <div class="col-sm-7 smallbox box-1"> box1 </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 smallbox box-2"> box2 </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 smallbox box-3"> box3 </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 smallbox box-4"> box4 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 right-wrapper box-5"> box 5 </div>
</div>
```

**Your relative CSS will be**

```
/* use of flex-box for equal height columns */
.main-wrapper{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.left-wrapper{padding:0}
.smallbox {color:#FFFFFF; min-height:100px;}
.box-1{ background:#c49a6c}
.box-2{ background:#bcbec0}
.box-3{ background:#9b8579}
.box-4{ background:#3c2415}
.box-5{ background:#726658;color:#FFF}
```