# .col-md-12 applied to a div does not occupy 100% of the width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am learning to model, and I am adding a div with the word "holi1", it is supposed that it should occupy 12 columns, that is to say the entire width of the container that has it. but I would like to know why it does not occupy 100% of the width. How can I correct it?

[image]

```
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
<body>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 d-flex   justify-content-center align-items-center contenedor_centrado">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 botones_centrados d-flex align-items-center" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                    holi1
                </div>                  
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Xqxhs0Ggp1SSmk7226AV?p=preview

Comment: one of your other classes may be overriding

Comment: Not where I can fiddle with it, but often problems occur if you don't follow the bootstrap structure.  Unlike most CSS you can't sprinkle classes anywhere.  In this case I don't believe you can nest rows like that, you need a column between one of the rows or just get rid of one.  Notice how rows columns alternate for nesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661416/84206

Comment: And as Fred mentioned might have some overrides.  Start removing the extra classes not related to the bootstrap layout and work backwards in browser inspector turning off classes.  If that fixes the issue you will have identified the conflict and can focus on that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two layers of "row" classes nested in each other. If you want to have both, then you need to add col-12 to the inner row to make it occupy the full width:

```
<body>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 d-flex   justify-content-center align-items-center contenedor_centrado">
            <div class="row col-12">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 botones_centrados d-flex align-items-center" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                    holi1
                </div>                  
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: should I also put col-md-12 etc ... too?

Comment: I had understood that the rows should not put the cabbage classes

Comment: cabbage classes? Do you mean column? It may not be the smartest thing to do in the long run, when your markup become more complicated, but it will work. All these classes are just hooks to apply CSS styling, so as long as the style rules don't conflict, it will work.

Comment: If you have col-12, col-md-12 is redundant. You need to read more about how the breakpoints work in Bootstrap.

Comment: Not a criticism but consideration: It's more "proper" to have row, column, row, column nesting rather than putting both a row and column class on a single element.  The former is tested and supported by bootstrap, and the latter may be quirky in some scenarios.

Comment: @AaronLS Can you replicate my example with the best practice to understand you much better? I would appreciate it very much to learn more and to make myself more clear

Comment: @AaronLS I agree, I'm not advocating combining row and col classes.

Comment: Don't have access to a desktop right now but basically you can have a single column between the two rows: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting