# Boostrap how add img align with other img

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello i have a problem with my code :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.plumenshopus.com/i/2018/08/four-chaleur-tournante-pyrolyse-candy-fcpk-electrique-encastrable-symbole-brandt-darty-pulsee-brassee-electrolux-gaz-air-brasse-vapeur-smeg-catalyse-mini-ariston-pulse-difference-615x385.jpg" alt="bloc1" /></div>
            <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.plumenshopus.com/i/2018/08/four-chaleur-tournante-pyrolyse-candy-fcpk-electrique-encastrable-symbole-brandt-darty-pulsee-brassee-electrolux-gaz-air-brasse-vapeur-smeg-catalyse-mini-ariston-pulse-difference-615x385.jpg" alt="bloc1" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.plumenshopus.com/i/2018/08/four-chaleur-tournante-pyrolyse-candy-fcpk-electrique-encastrable-symbole-brandt-darty-pulsee-brassee-electrolux-gaz-air-brasse-vapeur-smeg-catalyse-mini-ariston-pulse-difference-615x385.jpg" alt="bloc1" /></div>
            <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.plumenshopus.com/i/2018/08/four-chaleur-tournante-pyrolyse-candy-fcpk-electrique-encastrable-symbole-brandt-darty-pulsee-brassee-electrolux-gaz-air-brasse-vapeur-smeg-catalyse-mini-ariston-pulse-difference-615x385.jpg" alt="bloc1" /></div>
        </div>
```

And i have this result : 
[result bootstrap picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfnE9.jpg)

And i want one other img likes this :

[results final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWv0I.jpg)

How can i add other image with bootstrap for the final results ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested rows with bootstrap grid system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659471/nested-rows-with-bootstrap-grid-system)

Comment: Use 3 `col-4` per row instead of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my interpretation of your question, using a 2 columns inside a row and further dividing the first column into columns would work.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row main">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/1200" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tcjrtb

*Correct me if my understanding of the question is wrong.*

Comment: Great ! Thank you, but why the responsive doesn't works ?

Comment: Responsive image? Didn't quite get you. Can you explain

Comment: The images are well placed on laptop but I want them to be one after another on phones

Comment: Responsive for phones, you see ?

Comment: That's because we have to explicitly mention the responsive classes like col-xs-12 to take up the full row in mobiles and col-sm-4 to take 1/3rd of screen width for any bigger screen. I made the code responsive now, check for reference.

Comment: @Maxime It's always a good thing if you mark the question as 'answered' so others know this question was addressed and doesn't need attention anymore, unless you have more questions regarding this. Just a friendly reminder. Hope you got all your questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="" alt="bloc1" /></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

This code should do the work. [Simple application of bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width)

See [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJxqyX)