# Using more than 12 spaces worth of columns in a row with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question about the Bootstrap. In my case I'm displaying a list of posts and I am using the column 6 size (`col-lg-6`) more than two times within a row. I know that the row accepts only 12 columns at all.

Is this okay to be used in this way?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

[image: example layout]

The result I get is fine so I assume that it's okay to be used in this context of displaying posts.

Comment: It's Okay the rule of twelve is just a limit to display aside but you can nest in a single row more than 12 if you want they are just floated elements

Comment: If there isn't a problem don't worry about it

Comment: If you go to the example grids on the bootstrap page http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid ... you can see are nested col-xs more than 12 so there is no problem with that... check the **Example: Column wrapping**

Comment: Thanks @Danko. So in this case as screenshot shown, would you do it in this way if you would be using bootstrap or would you example do it with lists?

Comment: ALl is your choice if all the items will have the same height I don't see any problem to do that ... do it with list will have other styles maybe you don't want and will have to overrride ... Now in order to get the most clean grid and code can be more opinions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 grid, does it \*really\* matter how many columns are in a row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502342/bootstrap-3-grid-does-it-really-matter-how-many-columns-are-in-a-row)