# Horizontally centered Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/4cay7537/)**

I have a case where I want my bootstrap columns to horizontally center themselves.

To achieve this, I have used the following rules

**CSS:**

```
div[class^=col-] {
  float: none;/* Overwrites float left */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Then If 4 columns are there they should come in a line. And if there are 3 columns then they should be centered.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- The fourth column falls down -->
<div class='row text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-1">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
</div>
<!-- Works Fine and centers the columns -->    
<div class='row text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-1">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
</div>
```

It works fine if I have just 1,2 or 3 columns but when I get 4 columns, one of the columns falls down to a new line. To solve this issue, I have tried reducing the width to say `24.7%`. But again this does not work in all screens. So I have to keep changing the width.

I would love to know why width `25%` is not taking the `25%` width and falling down. And how to solve this issue and keep them always in the center.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/4cay7537/)**

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? `col-2` is only in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Oh. thanks for letting me know. I just used that as a custom class there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove:

```
div[class^=col-] {
    float: none;/* Overwrites float left */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
}
```

and you can add to the .row class:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you're using bootstrap v4 there are added flexbox classes, which you can use:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Yeah, if the bootstrap version is 4, its classes are recommended. Otherwise add the flex properties to your custom class, like .[prefix-]row-flex or similar, not to .row

Answer (score 2):

You should create a special class (ie: `row-centered`) for this case, and *not* override the Bootstrap grid.

```
.row-centered > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/EXmotvfGtG

Answer (score 1):

Give `display: flex` to the `row`. Using this method will work in all screens.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cay7537/8/)

```css
div[class^=col-] {
  float: none;  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
}
body {
  color: white;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
    background: red;
}
.col-2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- The fourth column falls down -->
<div class='row row-1 text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-1">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
</div>
<!-- Works Fine and centers the columns -->  
<div class='row text-center'>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-1">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-2">Hi</div>
</div>


<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;    
            background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
    About this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/q/23502342/1366033'>Bootstrap 3 grid, does it *really* matter how many columns are in a row?</a><br/>
    Fork This Skeleton Here <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootrsap 3.0 Skeleton</a><br/>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess with `display: flex`, the `display inline block` for the `cols` wont be necessary.